# Do the tangent planes to surfaces of objects in 3 space cancel out?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

It seems like for things like spheres, for every tangent plane in one direction, there is another going in the same direction on the "other side" of the object, if it's symmetric then across the line of symmetry? Are there objects for which this isn't true? What is this property called?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Take two parallel planes far outside any object and slowly move them toward each other until each touches the object at single or possibly multiple points (i.e., are tangent).  One can always do this.  Because it works for every object, it has no special name, that I know of.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: The object in question needs to be a closed surface (no boundary) and smooth, of course.